# Laravel Excel import - how to get imported users

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I need to import users from excel sheet.
And all is great but after the import I have to do some more things with those imported users. How can I get them in my controller after importing?

I try to follow the Laravel Excel documentation but it's very cryptic :(

Anyway I have a class UserImport as in their example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class UsersImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
           'name'     => $row[0],
           'email'    => $row[1], 
           'password' => Hash::make($row[2]),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in my controller i have:

```
$import = new UsersImport();
    $import->import(request()->file('xlsfile'));
    if($import->errors()->count())
    {
        dump($import->errors());
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Success<br>';

        dd($import);
    }
```

Unfortunately the $import contains instead of my records this:

```
App\Imports\UsersImport {#372 ▼
  #output: null
  #errors: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation under Importing basics

> Importing to array or collection
>
> If you want to bypass the ToArray or ToCollection concerns and want to
> have an array of imported data in your controller (beware of
> performance!), you can use the ::toArray() or ::toCollection() method.
>
> `$array = Excel::toArray(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');`
>
> `$collection = Excel::toCollection(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');`

In your case you might be able to access `$import->toArray()` directly. But i'm not sure. Give it a go.

Comment: $import->toArray() unfortunately not working - it says: A filepath or UploadedFile needs to be passed to start the import. And when I give it the file like this $import->toArray(request()->file('xlsfile'));
The result is just the same: App\Imports\UsersImport {#372 ▼
  #output: null
  #errors: []
}